# Jenkins occasionally does not pick up the committed source of svn code

Tags: jenkins, svn

A job in jenkins which gets auto triggered after any code commit, occasionally does not pick up the committed source code.

The code committed in a model on 14th June was not found in the build triggered on 20th June

After a dummy check-in with a new activity name, the committed code is reflecting in the module in the build triggered on 21st June.

SCM: SVN and I made sure we are pulling svn head

And this is occasionally happening.

Any suggestion please?

Comment: Is there anything in the console log from the build where it did not update to the correct version?

Comment: Nothing like that in the console log.
It picks the file but I don't see any version though I'm pulling always the HEAD version. This happens occasionally.